# SwiftUI - Updating @EnvironmentObject doesn't update the UI

Tags: ios, xcode, environment-variables, swiftui

I'm trying to update an @EnvironmentObject called AppState with a Bool indicating that there's some process happening and show in activity indicator.
In the code below I call a method in my viewModel to log the user in. Before I call login(), I update the appState's "isWaiting" property, which gets passed into the activity indicator class and a spinner is show on the parent view. When the login method returns, I set the prop to false to kill the spinner.

```
Button(action: {
                        self.loginViewModel.username = self.username
                        self.loginViewModel.password = self.password
                        
                        self.appState.isWaiting = true
                        
                        self.loginViewModel.login() { token in
                            if !token.isEmpty {
                                self.userToken = token
                            }
                            
                            self.appState.isWaiting = false
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Log in")
                            .bold()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
```

However, it's not working... I can get the spinner to show if I comment out the line inside the closure to set it to false, but when I uncomment it, nothing shows (but both lines are getting hit in debug mode)
Any glaring, obvious things I'm doing wrong?

Here's the AppState class:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
@Published var isHidden: Bool = false
@Published var isWaiting: Bool = false
```

}

In a parent View, I set it as an @EnvironmentObject var

```
struct ChooserView: View {
@ObservedObject var homeState: AppState
}
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.bottom, .top])
    .environmentObject(homeState)
```

In a LoginDrawerView, a child of ChooserView, I reference the AppState

```
struct LoginDrawerView: View {
@ObservedObject private var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = LoginViewModel(service: LoginService())
@EnvironmentObject private var appState: AppState
```

In the same view, I call the login() method of my viewModel, which is the code I pasted above. Without recreating the entire app here, I'm not sure what else I could provide to recreate this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Updated with additional context

Comment: Does your login method dispatch its completion handler into the main queue.  If not you need to do that for UI updates.

Comment: As requested, please show a [mcve]. It should be pretty simple to replace the login with a simple delay that calls the completion. At least show how you actually use the app state.